# Open a blank window keeping the same location as the parent window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's the problem. I'm trying to print a calendar. I have to load some css but all the css links have an absolute path like this `/path/to/css.css`. So if I simply open the window with:

```
var win = open('', '_blank')
win.document.write(htmlContent)
```

This will correctly draw the html but it won't load the css because it's not pointing to the right hostname.

Changing the location afterward will create a redirect so it's not really a solution.

I'm able to achieve what I want with this:

```
function open_calendar(content) {
  var win = open(window.location, 'Calendar')        

  win.addEventListener('load', function () {
    win.document.write(content)
  })

  return win
}
```

The window open the same location, when the page is loaded, then it changes the content to what I wanted. The result is that it still use the same location and allows me to draw my custom html. The downside is that I have to load the page which might take some time... I was wondering if there was a less hacky way to achieve the same result.

Comment: So why are you loading the CSS like that? And not with an absolute path?

Comment: another option is to capture current server to a var using window.location.hostname and pass the concatenated value into your css path (using a string replace if needed)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element to your html before doing your write. And set it to the base url you want the relative urls to use.

```
<base href="http://example.com/some/path">
```

`<base>` tells the browser what base url to use for relative links. So if you had set base to `http://example.com/base` and had a relative link `/path/to/css.css` the resulting url used would be `http://example.com/base/path/to/css.css`